# Configure Spring Boot to Prevent Logjam Attack

Tags: spring, security, ssl, https, spring-boot

Firefox v39 will no longer connect to my web application over HTTPS.  I'm using Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat and I've made sure I'm using the latest version of Boot (v1.2.5).  Firefox shows the following error message:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to [website]. SSL received a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman key in Server Key Exchange handshake message. (Error code: ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key)

I understand this is to protect against a known vulnerability called [Logjam](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/05/https-crippling-attack-threatens-tens-of-thousands-of-web-and-mail-servers/).  A solution for Tomcat is provided at [weakdh.org](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html#tomcat).

Spring Boot passes SSL configuration to Tomcat via [application.properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) and as such I have added `server.ssl.ciphers` to my application.properties as follows:

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=/home/ec2-user/boot.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=...
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=...
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
```

After restarting boot, I notice the following in my log file:

`WARN 2674 [main] --- o.a.t.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory    : None of the ciphers specified are supported by the SSL engine : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, ...`

Additionally, connecting using Firefox fails with the following message:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to [website] was interrupted while the page was loading.

And I see the following in my log file:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)`

Unfortunately I'm no encryption expert.  Can anyone suggest how to fix this?  Do I need to recreate my HTTPS certificate?

Comment: Yes - you'll need to update the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade server Java on the server from 1.7 to 1.8.

- `sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk`
- `sudo yum install java-1.8.0`

After this was complete, no other configuration was necessary.  Not even modyfing Tomcat as per the advice at weakdh.org.

Comment: Just wondering, if you are exposing rest services, do your rest clients have to do something especial or not at all?

Comment: The REST clients connect over HTTPS and authenticate themselves via a username and password.  No client-side certificate is used.

Comment: @Adam, I am on java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212 but I failed when doing test with https://www.ssllabs.com.

Comment: I'm running OpenJDK 11.0.8 (2020-07-14), and even enabling just the ciphers in your post (in a .properties config file), my server still uses DH. Any suggestions?